# Monotone interpolation wrong curve for the last point

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I'm trying to smooth out the chart lines using monotone interpolation. However, my graph has weird ending.
[image: chart using monotone interpolation]
When I change the interpolation to default, everything seems correct.

[image: chart using default interpolation]

What is wrong with the monotone interpolation?

Comment: Show us your data and your drawing code.

Comment: There's nothing wrong with the interpolation, it does exactly what it's supposed to do. If this is unsuitable in your case, you need to use a different interpolation method.